# Restrict user to run specific sudo command

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo

Here is a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

user='my_sudo_user'
sudo -lU $user
```

I was trying to limit my `non_sudo_user` to have the ability to run this script. Using `visudo`, I tried:

```
non_sudo_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash /full/path/script.sh
non_sudo_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -lU
non_sudo_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -lU *   # unsafe
```

None of them work. I get this message:

```
Sorry, user non_sudo_user is not allowed to execute 'list' as my_sudo_user on host123.
```

But I provided -l in `sudoer` file.

What can I do? This is Ubuntu by the way.

**EDIT**:

I actually run this script:

```
for u in $(awk -F'[/:]' '{if($3>=1000&&$3!=65534) print $1}' /etc/passwd); do sudo -lU $u ; done
```

So I don't have a definite list of users ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
complete rewrite after OP provided more information.

Specify the user in /etc/sudoers as having permission to execute `/usr/sbin/sudo`.

This will allow them to execute the sudo command, but they will have no permissions to run any other commands.

I just tested this on CentOS-7.3.1611 with a brand new user account:

`testusr ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/sudo`

**I do not know if there are any security implications of specifying the sudo command itself in the list of allowed commands**
Please review and test before you rely on this in a production environment...it may be insecure.

Comment: Thanks, but it still complain it doesn't have permission to execute 'list'.

Comment: Okay, so I guess I don't understand why you would use sudo to run a script that invokes sudo to list the users commands. Just tell the user to execute `sudo -l` for their own commands or `sudo -lU someuser` to list the commands someuser is allowed to run.

Comment: I am trying to run a report as the non_sudo_user to test whether "my_sudo_user" has sudo privilege or not. The best reliable way is to run sudo -lU as far as I know. The reason the non_sudo_user can't have full privilege because it is meant for read-only.

Comment: thank you, the `/usr/sbin/sudo` will allow my non sudo user to have full sudo privilege. It's okay, I might have to work around with this for now, but I am hoping someone could come up with a solution, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: Hmm, did you test what happens if testuser runs: `sudo sudo -s`? I suspect that results in a root shell.

Comment: @derobert no i didn't but I suspected as much, thus my warning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only list the commands a different user can run if you can run arbitrary commands as (ALL) that user. So instead...

In sudoers:

```
non_sudo_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -l
```

And to list them, running as `non_sudo_user`:

```shell
for target_user in user1 user2 user3... ; do
    sudo -u "$target_user" sudo -l
done
```

Comment: this works, but using `-u` I am stuck on users who aren't sudoer as I am asked for password. That's the expected behavior, but not quite what I am looking for. It was the reason i went with `-lU` (`U` goes with the list option).

Comment: @CppLearner I think (haven't tested) you could change the sudoer rule to allow ALL instead of non_sudo_user, if I'm understanding you correctly. Though you probably shouldn't... (Or maybe change my_sudo_user to ALL, not exactly sure what you're going for)

Comment: @CppLearner oh! I see you edited your question—I've updated the answer. This should do what you want.